# Azure AD as an OpenID Connect Provider for an Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, openid

I have an `Azure AD` named `FOO` where I have a bunch of users. I created an `Azure ADB2C` as a Resource inside the `FOO` directory, named `BAR`, in which I want to signUp/signIn users. However, if you are already a user in `FOO` I want you to be able to connect via an `Identity Provider`.

Is this possible? I did not manage to make this work. I'm currently following these docs:

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow) This seems like it works for `FOO AD` for `FOO ADB2C`.

[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow) This seems like it would fit my scenario.

[3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-user-flow) This seems like it would work for `FOO ADB2C` to `BAR ADB2C`.

Even tho the second docs fit my scenario, I see that it's mandatory to use custom policies, which I'm not a fan of. Is there any workaround? Has anybody faced this scenario before?

Comment: I think the first scenario is what you are looking for. What issues are you running into?

Comment: If I am following the first scenario, I'm getting an error in `https://jwt.ms`: `AADB2C99002: User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.`.

Comment: So you have a signup/signin policy and you have added your Azure AD as an identity provider? And this happens after you click the button to login with your AAD?

Comment: I have a `Sign In` user flow.

Comment: Ah, that could be the reason.. B2C expects the user to already exist in a signin flow. Signin/signup flow would automatically create the user object in the B2C tenant if it is missing. Sounds like the scenario might not be possible with a standard signin flow.

Comment: @juunas that was it, `1` works with an `SignIn/SignUp` flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a signin flow, Azure AD B2C is expecting the user object to exist in the B2C directory.

You'll have to either:

1. Use a signin/signup flow that makes B2C create the user if it does not already exist
2. Use a custom policy that allows local users to sign in + creates users objects for your AAD users if they don't exist yet

Answer (score 1):

You can also add custom OIDC identity provider

1. In your FOO directory register new App that will represent AAD B2C, and generate client secret (don't forget to save it somewhere) - this and application Id needs to be added in next step
2. Add new Identity provider in BAR tenant as OIDC (Identity providers on LHS)
3. In metadata field paste https://login.microsoftonline.com/FOO.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
4. Set FOO for domain hint, oid for user id, name for display name, given_name for given name, family_name for surname and unique_name for Email (that is in my case)
   After that you should be able to choose your FOO tenant as additional button in your user flow, just like Google, Facebook or whatever you have there

The other option is to use custom policies.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's like social media account. If user signs out in BAR tenant he/she won't be signed out in FOO tenant but this is a story to be continued in different thread and requires some hacks :)

Comment: That is currently what I'm facing. I saw that I need to send the user to the IDP's `end_session_endpoint` and use `post_logout_redirect_uri` to get him back to my page.

Comment: Do you have any insights on this? I'm currently stuck on the IDP's page because for some reason it doesn't rediret to my `post_logout_redirect_uri`.

Comment: How do you call the endpoint? Is it https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant guid/oauth/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://your_app.com?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have opened a ticket at Microsoft for this. Anyways this link to IDPs end session endpoint needs to be provided as a post_logout_refirect_uri parameter passed to B2C on your Web app. Don't forget to add FOO end session endpoint to app registration in BAR without parameter.